# How to get value after 2nd hash in input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My below t-sql only works when there is one hash symbol in the input parameter.

How can I change it to so I can get the value after the 2nd hash symbol?

I think I need to use a combination of `REVERSE` and `RIGHT` but I can't figure it out.

```
DECLARE @SEAL_SECURITY3 As Varchar(50); SET @SEAL_SECURITY3 = NULL;
DECLARE @SEAL_SECURITY As Varchar(50); SET @SEAL_SECURITY = 'MS-7#MS-8#MS-9'

SET @SEAL_SECURITY3 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('#', @SEAL_SECURITY) = 0 THEN NULL 
ELSE SUBSTRING(@SEAL_SECURITY, CHARINDEX('#', @SEAL_SECURITY) + 1, LEN(@SEAL_SECURITY) - CHARINDEX('#', @SEAL_SECURITY) + 1) 
END 

SELECT @SEAL_SECURITY3
```

The result of this is MS-8#MS-9

Desired result is  MS-9

**UPDATE**

is it possible to get the Desired result by changing the `SET ELSE` block as opposed to the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Multiple examples are probably helpful.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achive?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your are using SQL SERVER and In your string, count of `#` is always less and equals to 4 then below script will help to get desire result

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@SEAL_SECURITY,'#','.'),1)
```

Comment: This works but is it possible to get the same result by changing the SET ELSE block as opposed to the SELECT statement?

Comment: Yes Just replace else part with `PARSENAME(REPLACE(@SEAL_SECURITY,'#','.'),1)`

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using a SQL Server Version before 2012:

```
SELECT RIGHT(@SEAL_SECURITY, CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(@SEAL_SECURITY))-1)
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I am using Sql Server 2014 however so I have accepted the other answer. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question originally!